# Bizarre behavior observed in make 3.81 when attempting to use a reassigned variable as a dependancy

Tags: c++, dynamic, makefile, gnu

I'm running into a bizarre problem with a C++ makefile.  I rewrote it this afternoon because the old one I was using made me want to kill myself, and I'm running into a weird problem regarding variable reassignment and dynamic dependancies.

for the purposes of this question, assume the following values:

```
OBJMOD_MODULENAME = obj/lib/foo.o obj/lib/bar.o obj/lib/quux.o
LIBDIR         = lib/
CXX            = g++
CXXLIBLINK     = -shared
LIB            = -lm -lpt
```

I have a target of the following format:

```
modulename: OBJ_CURRENTMOD = $(OBJMOD_MODULENAME)
modulename: $(OBJMOD_MODULENAME) lib/metrics.so
```

and later on, another of the following format:

```
$(LIBDIR)%.so: $(OBJ_CURRENTMOD)
    $(CXX) $(CXXLIBLINK) -o $@ $(OBJ_CURRENTMOD) $(LIB)
```

Lines in code blocks always appear in the order in which they are presented in the code blocks, however over the course of debugging I have changed the position of the blocks relative to each other.

The problem occurs after I change a source file and try to recompile with 'make modulename'.  Building the object files works as expected, but rebuilding the library does not happen if the file already exists, i.e. the dependencies specified by `$(OBJ_CURRENTMOD)` are ignored.  Using `$(OBJMOD_MODULENAME)` in the library dependencies works as expected.  I have verified in a number of ways that the value of `$(OBJ_CURRENTMOD)` is as expected (stick `echo 
$(OBJ_CURRENTMOD)` on the first line of the library target for example), but no matter what I try, the variable does not seem to update in time to trigger a recompile due to dependancy checking.

As I was typing this, I found a workaround:

```
OBJMOD_MODULENAME = obj/lib/foo.o obj/lib/bar.o obj/lib/quux.o
LIBDIR         = lib/
CXX            = g++
CXXLIBLINK     = -shared
LIB            = -lm -lpt

modulename: OBJ_CURRENTMOD = $(OBJMOD_MODULENAME)
modulename: $(OBJMOD_MODULENAME) lib/metrics.so

$(LIBDIR)%.so: herp $(OBJ_CURRENTMOD)
    $(CXX) $(CXXLIBLINK) -o $@ $(OBJ_CURRENTMOD) $(LIB)

herp: $(OBJ_CURRENTMOD)
```

This dummy target tacked in before the variable reference seems to force it to update and solves my problem.  Is this a bug in make or something?  make --version indicates GNU make 3.81.  Can anyone else confirm this weird behavior?  Am I just doing something horribly stupid?  I've been staring at it for hours, I wouldn't be that surprised.

edit: turns out that wasn't really fixing it, it was just trapping it into running every time regardless of whether or not it needed it.

To verify the altered value:

```
$(LIBDIR)%.so: $(OBJ_CURRENTMOD)
    echo $(OBJ_CURRENTMOD)
    $(CXX) $(CXXLIBLINK) -o $@ $(OBJ_CURRENTMOD) $(LIB)
```

Comment: How does OBJMOD_MODULENAME get its value? What is the library target you want rebuilt? The snippets you've shown don't show enough to understand your makefile

Comment: It _seems_ to work using make 3.82, but I've had to make some guesses at the missing parts of your makefile to try and reproduce it. What you show doesn't explain why the `$(LIBDIR)%.so` target should get rebuilt for `modulename`, or what `$(OBJMOD_MODULENAME)` is set to or how it's set.

Comment: Jon- Everything else builds correctly.  There is a similar rule to the shown one for .so files that applies instead to .o files and builds them from .cpp files in a different directory (this component works as intended).  OBJMOD_MODULENAME was a brain-o, I've updated the names to reflect what I meant.

Comment: Why are you expecting a lib to be rebuilt by 'make modulename'? It depends in the .o files and metrics.so but neither of them matches the pattern $(LIBDIR)%.so. The target-specific variable value is only set when running rules for modulename and its prerequisites, but $(LIBDIR)%.so isn't used for any of its prerequisites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in one of my comments, I don't see how the `$(LIBDIR)%.so` pattern will match any pre-requisite of `modulename` but assuming `metrics.so` is meant to be `lib/metrics.so` then it will be used to build `lib/metrics.so`.

As interjay pointed out, "*As with automatic variables, these values are only available within the context of a target's recipe (and in other target-specific assignments).*" They can't be used in a target pattern or in a list of pre-requisites, which explains why the target doesn't get rebuilt when one of the pre-requisites in `$(OBJ_MODULENAME)` changes.

To make `$(OBJ_CURRENTMOD)` valid in the prerequisites list you'll need to use [secondary expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Secondary-Expansion)

```
.SECONDEXPANSION:
$(LIBDIR)%.so: $$(OBJ_CURRENTMOD)
        $(CXX) $(CXXLIBLINK) -o $@ $(OBJ_CURRENTMOD) $(LIB)
```

Comment: Awesome.  I can't test this for another few hours.  If it works, I'm bookmarking this post and you win my first ever upvote, just as soon as my rep is high enough to do upvotes.  Consider this a hypothetical IOU.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the [target-specific variable value](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Target_002dspecific) `OBJ_CURRENTMOD` in the prerequisite list of the `$(LIBDIR)%.so` rule. This is not allowed: Target-specific variables may only be used in the recipe of a target.

Another issue is that you are defining the variable `OBJ_MODULENAME` and later accessing a different variable `$(OBJMOD_MODULENAME)`, which hasn't been assigned to.

Comment: That variable assignment is valid syntax, it sets a [target-specific variable value](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Target_002dspecific)

Comment: @JonathanWakely: You're right, I was unaware of that. But it seems that the variable was still used incorrectly as my updated answer shows.

Comment: I changed the variable names and missed that one, thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: I think interjay has it, the docs say "_As with automatic variables, these values are only available within the context of a target's recipe (and in other target-specific assignments)._"